# actionbarsherlock tabs orientation change json

Tags: android, tabs, orientation, actionbarsherlock

I am currently using ActionBarSherlock to create my actionbar. Right now, I have tabs that are created from an array which is selected from an Id in an previous activity. By default the app starts on this page, and defaults to selecting the first tab of the first array. The problem I am having is when the orientation changes, and the activity is destroyed and created again, causing the first tab of the first array to display. I attempted to have the tab display the saved tab when it is preforms onCreate,  but I get interesting, but wrong results. I am not a wizard when it comes to Android, and I am hoping that this is a simple fix.

What the app does is the user selects a category from a previous activity, and based on the id that is sent from the intent, different tabs are sometimes needed or not needed. So I used an array to build the tabs for the category. Once a tab is selected it does a JSON query and grabs info and displays it in a listview.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.pt_section);

    //use array within array to make tabs
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    ActionBar.Tab tab =null;     
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        
    String[][] section_id_name = {
            { "News", "Opinion", "Features", "Sports", "Sustainable Life"}
            ,{ "News", "Opinion", "Features", "Sports"}
            ,{ "News", "Features" }

            };

    String[][] section_id = {
            { "1", "4", "13", "41", "42"}
            ,{ "5", "7", "11", "12"}
            ,{ "8", "9" }

            };


                Intent intent = getIntent();
                //Check if sid is null
                 sid = intent.getStringExtra(PT_newspapers.INTENT_ID);  
                if (sid == null){
                    sid = "0";          
                }

                    sid_int = Integer.parseInt(sid);
                    for (int i = 0; i < section_id[sid_int].length; i++) { 
                        tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
                        tab.setText(section_id_name[sid_int][i]);
                        //sid = sid1id[i];
                        tab.setTag(section_id[sid_int][i]);
                        tab.setTabListener(this);
                        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab); 
                        System.out.println(section_id[sid_int][i]);

            }

                    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

                        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 1));
                        System.out.println("not null!"); 
                    }       




}//End onCreate method


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

    @Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    sectionid = tab.getTag().toString();
    System.out.println("Tab selected with id of :" + sectionid);       
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    System.out.println("Now executing LoadAllProducts class");
    new LoadAllProducts().execute(); //Calls to class LoadAllProducts
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // getting values from selected ListItem


            String id2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_tag)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PT_Article.class);
            // sending sid to next activity
           in.putExtra(INTENT_ID, id2);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            //startActivity(in);

            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            //mError.setText("Error, No stories loaded");
        }

    }); 


} //End onTabSelected
```

Once the orientation has changed, the app works with displaying the proper stories on tab changes, but when it is initially switched, it will save the current tab, but displays the wrong data.

I have been trying to figure this out all day, but have had no luck, any insight would be greatly appreciated.